# ViewComponent Not Found from class library .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have an issue using a .Net 6 Class Library to create ViewComponent to use it many Web app.

I have create a Class library :

[image]

The code :

```cs
public class HelpComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

----- CsHtml

<h1>
Test
</h1>

----- Project config : 

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views/**/*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Afterthat I configure my Web app in asp.net 6 in program.cs :

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
         typeof(Peinture.Commons.ViewComponents.HelpComponent).Assembly, "commons"
    ));
});
```

And finally I try to import my componant inside a View :

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(Peinture.Commons.ViewComponents.HelpComponent))
```

Do you have any idea why I got this error ? :

[image]

I've tried to change the code inside program.cs with different things I found on internet but nothing changed.

Comment: can [this blog](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/07/16/loading-view-components-from-a-class-library-in-asp-net-core.aspx) help you?

Comment: I followed this blog... and it didn't help me

Comment: yes and could you pls try `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` like what I post below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my side.

[image]

Then I found [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-conditionally) and adding `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
         typeof(ClassLibrary1.ViewComponents.SimpleViewComponent).Assembly
    ));
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried to user AddRazorPages() but i've got an issue with someting else. I fixe the other thing and know it's working fine.

Comment: thanks for your update and it's good to see your codes working now